# How to load schema.graphql in laravel graphql-playground without using public folder and php artisan

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse, graphql-playground

I am developing a graphql based laravel app and using Lighthouse for the purpose.
Now I have to access the playground through localhost/blog/graphql-playground (without using artisan or writing public every time), for this purpose I have copied content of 'public' folder to the index folder. Every controller including graphql-playground seems to work but playground cannot fetch schema.graphql placed in root directorie's graphql folder (localhost/blog/graphql) with error 'Server cannot be reached'. but if I give URL localhost/blog/public/graphql it will work. I have went through all the possible files and couldn't file settings to be changed. I tried deleting content of public folder. after that even /public wouldn't work.

How do I fix this?
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feJzu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your artisan server is running on port `8000`. So try with `http://localhost:8000/graphql`.